# Quotients by Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

First off sorry for being lazy and not typing it up but I've got exams and time is not on my side.
 $J=(1-2i)$, does this mean than $J=r_1(1-2i)r_2$ with $r_i \in R$

Also for the kernel of $\psi$ why does y=2x 
I thought the kernel of $\psi$ the $x$ such that $x \in J$ so any x that can be stated in the form above.

Comment: Since it is a commutative ring J=$r_1$(1-2i). To find the quotients: set 1-2i=0 i.e. 2i=1; Thus The Quotients group is {Z+0i, Z+i}

Comment: @ShreedharBhat Your computation of the quotient is wrong. $(1 - 2i)$ is one of the $2$ primes of $\Bbb Z[i]$ over $(5)\subseteq\Bbb Z$, and because $\Bbb Q(i)$ is a degree $2$ (Galois) extension of $\Bbb Q$, we must have $2 = ref$, and $r = 2$ so $e = f = 1$. Hence, $\Bbb Z[i]/(1 - 2i)\cong\Bbb Z/(5)$.

Comment: ...of course, the argument in the question also shows in a much more elementary way that the quotient is $\Bbb Z/(5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $J=(1-2i)$, does this mean than $J=r_1(1-2i)r_2$ with $r_i \in R$?

That's almost correct, although you're not taking $r\in R$, you're taking $r\in\Bbb Z[i]$ ($J$ is an ideal of $\Bbb Z[i]$ such that $R = \Bbb Z[i]/J$). Moreover, because $\Bbb Z[i]$ is commutative, you only need one $r$. That is,
$$
J = \{r\cdot(1 - 2i)\mid r\in\Bbb Z[i]\}\subseteq \Bbb Z[i].
$$

> Also for the kernel of $\psi$ why does $y=2x$
>   I thought the kernel of $\psi$ the $x$ such that $x \in J$ so any $x$ that can be stated in the form above.

The kernel of $\psi$ is the set of $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\psi(n) = 0_R$ in $R$. Read this carefully, this says $\ker\psi\subseteq\Bbb Z,$ which is the domain of $\psi$: it does not make sense to consider the kernel as a subset of $J$, which is technically not even a subset of the codomain of $\psi$! Perhaps you were remembering that the canonical homomorphism $\pi : \Bbb Z[i]\to\Bbb Z[i]/J$ has kernel $\ker\pi = J$, but that is not the situation here.

Now, you can translate this into a condition involving $J$:
$$
n\in\ker\psi\iff\psi(n) = 0\iff [n] = 0\iff n\equiv0\pmod{J}\iff n\in J.
$$
For $n$ to be an element of $J$, we must have $n = (x + yi)(1 - 2i)$, because $J$ is the set of elements of the form $r(1 - 2i)$ in $\Bbb Z[i]$, and every $r\in\Bbb Z[i]$ is of the form $r = x + yi$ with $x,y\in\Bbb Z$. Note that here $x$ is *not* in the kernel of $\psi$: $n$ is in the kernel, and $x$ is just some integer such that $n = (x + yi)(1 - 2i)$.

Expanding this out gives
$$
n = (x + 2y) + (y - 2x)i,
$$
and since $n$ is just an integer, it follows that it has no imaginary part, so that $y - 2x = 0$, or $y = 2x$. Finally, plugging this back into the above expression for $n$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
n &= (x + 2y) + (y - 2x)i\\
&= (x + 2(2x)) + (2x - 2x)i\\
&= (x + 4x) + 0i\\
&= 5x,
\end{align*}
so that $n$ is a multiple of $5$. We have found that anything in the kernel must be of the form $n = 5x$, so that the kernel only contains integers which are multiples of $5$. (The proof actually leaves out a step IMO: it claims the kernel is $(5) = 5\Bbb Z\subseteq\Bbb Z$, but it does not show that *all* multiples of $5$ are in the kernel. You might want to prove this yourself as practice.)

Comment: Oh okay thank you very much, that helped a lot. I think the main problem was that I didn't notice $\psi$ had $\mathbb{Z}$ as the domain

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're in a commutative ring so $J = (1-2i) = \{r(1-2i) | r \in R \}$ but this is actually the same as what you've written by commutativity.
Now yes $ker(\phi)$ is a subset of $J$ but it is the elements that $\phi$ maps to zero from its domain, which is $\Bbb{Z}$. So the calculation it shows is has $n \in \Bbb{Z} \subset \Bbb{R}$ so that's why we have that the imaginary part at the end must be zero.